# Pass 2D array of pointers by reference to function

Tags: c++

I have a problem. I dont know how to pass 2D array of pointers to fuction by reference.

```
class SomeClass
{ 
//body of class
}


void somefunction(SomeClass ***array)
{
//body of function
}

int main()
{
SomeClass * array[10][10]
someFunction(array?????)
}
```

Anyone know how to pass this array by reference??

Comment: `void Somefunction(SomeClass * (&array)[10][10])`?

Answer (score 0):

Literally

```
void somefunction(SomeClass *(&array)[10][10])
{
}

int main()
{
  SomeClass *array[10][10];
  someFunction(array);
}
```